# Summation to Infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could someone explain a step by step solution to this? It's 1 mark but I missed the lesson and can't find anything on summation to infinity or how you'd go about it.
[image]

It's basic but my teacher completely aired me on this one.

Comment: Do you know about partial fractions?

Comment: you can cancel the $4$ from both sides

Comment: Now I do GitGud

Comment: Ahh yeh of course, thanks man!

Comment: Cheers. It would be good if you wrote a full answer below.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=2}^{n}\frac{4}{4r^2-4r-3}&=\sum_{r=2}^{n}(\frac{1}{2r-3}-\frac{1} {2r+1})
\\
&=1+\frac{1}{3}+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5})+...+(\frac{1}{2n-3}-\frac{1}{2n-3})-(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1})
\\
&=\frac{4}{3}-(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1})
\end{align}

So 
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{4}{4n^2-4n-3}&=\frac{4}{3}-\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1})
\\
&=\frac{4}{3}
\end{align}